# TextView displayed without using addView in Android

Tags: android, textview

I am new to Android.I have created a dynamic textview which is displayed on emulator,
but i am not adding this textview using **addView** then how it displayed?

Here is my code:

```
package com.DynamicTextField;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DynamicTextFieldActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private TextView tv ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Dynamic Text View Test\n");
        tv.setTextSize(18);
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

What is the best way of adding textview?

Can anyone help!

Thanks.

Comment: this code is fine and working then where is problem.

Comment: yes this code is working but i want explanation how it is working.

Comment: `setContentView` sets the Activity's view to whatever you pass to it.  Since you are passing a `TextView`, that's why it's getting displayed on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. `addView` can be called to add a `View` to a `ViewGroup` (a `View` capable of containing other `Views`). In your example, you are inside of an `Activity` and you are calling `setContentView` which sets the content to anything that extends `View`.

The normal way to use views in an activity is to either define your viewgroup in xml or programatically. If you do it programatically it would look something like:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(context);
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
layout.addView(tv);
```

Normally you would define the View in it's own class. But if you'd like you can do this all in onCreate of your activity, and use "this" in place of context.

Comment: :thanks for your reply,I have updated my question please go through that, any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `setContentView(tv);`

This sets your Content view to your TextView

Comment: :thanks for your reply,I have updated my question please go through that, any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are Calling setContentView by adding tv to the View.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to clear your android basics.

TextView is a view. In an activity this textview object can be add and we want to show this text view in our page then we have two methods.

First you have to create xml in layout folder and display it in activity by setContentView(layout).

Second way you have to add textview object and display only text view by setContentView.

For more info please visit  http://developer.android.com